# Tree structure in Js infinite loop issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have code to make a tree structure in Js if i use add_child to add a child to a item in the elements array it adds to the children of all the items in the elements array and there children and there children and there children and so on it makes a infinite loop

idk why it is not working

```js
let divBase = {
  Name: "",
  Type: "div",
  children: [],
  open: false
};

let elements = [];

let elementCounter = 0;

function add_child(parentName, childName) {
  let parent = findItem(parentName)
  let child = removeItem(childName)

  console.log(parent)
  console.log(child)

  if (child != null) {
    parent.children.push(child)
    console.log(parent)
    console.log(child)
    return true
  }
  return false
}

function removeItem(itemName) {
  var returnitem = null;

  function findAndRemove(arr, itemName) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var item = arr[i];
      if (item.Name === itemName) {
        returnitem = arr.splice(i, 1)[0];
        break;
      }
      if (item.children && item.children.length) {
        findAndRemove(item.children, itemName);
      }
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var item = elements[i];
    if (item.Name === itemName) {
      returnitem = elements.splice(i, 1)[0];
      break;
    }
    if (item.children && item.children.length) {
      findAndRemove(item.children, itemName);
    }
  }

  return returnitem;
}

function findItem(item) {
  let result = null;

  function search(children) {
    for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      const child = children[i];
      if (child.Name === item) {
        result = child;
        return;
      }
      if (child.children.length !== 0) {
        search(child.children);
      }
    }
  }

  search(elements);

  return result;
}

function selectItem(item) {
  let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("eitem");
  for (let i of elements) {
    i.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(24, 24, 24)";
  }
  document.getElementById(item).style.backgroundColor = "rgb(50, 50, 50)";
}

function getElementNum() {
  return elementCounter++;
}

function displayList(list, root, plase) {
  root.innerHTML = "";
  for (const item of list) {
    const itemEl = document.createElement("div");
    itemEl.className = "eitem";
    itemEl.id = item.Name;
    itemEl.draggable = true;
    itemEl.addEventListener("click", function() {
      selectItem(item.Name);
    });

    if (item.children.length != 0) {
      const button = document.createElement("button")
      const img = document.createElement("img")

      button.className = "eButton"
      img.className = "eImg"

      if (item.open == false) {
        img.src = "Icons/right.svg"
      } else {
        img.src = "Icons/down.svg"
      }

      button.appendChild(img)
      itemEl.appendChild(button)
    }

    const itemText = document.createTextNode(item.Name);
    const itemP = document.createElement("p");
    const itemb = document.createElement("b");

    itemP.className = "Etext";

    itemb.appendChild(itemText);
    itemP.appendChild(itemb);
    itemEl.appendChild(itemP);

    itemEl.addEventListener("dragstart", function(event) {
      event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", item.Name);
    });

    itemEl.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    });

    itemEl.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      let target = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain")
      add_child(item.Name, target)
      displayList(elements, document.getElementById("Explorer_contaner"));
    });

    root.appendChild(itemEl);
  }
}

function add_element(element) {
  if (element === "div") {
    let newElement = Object.assign({}, divBase);
    newElement.Name = "Div " + getElementNum();
    elements.push(newElement);
    displayList(elements, document.getElementById("Explorer_contaner"));
    console.log(elements);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

if i print the elements array it is like this

```
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

0 : {Name: 'Div 0', Type: 'div', children: Array(1), backgroundColor: '#2ecc71', width: 200, …}
1 : {Name: 'Div 1', Type: 'div', children: Array(1), backgroundColor: '#2ecc71', width: 200, …} 
2 : {Name: 'Div 2', Type: 'div', children:
> Array(1), backgroundColor: '#2ecc71', width: 200, …}
3 : {Name: 'Div 3', Type: 'div', children: Array(1), backgroundColor: '#2ecc71',
> width: 200, …}
4 : {Name: 'Div 5', Type: 'div', children: Array(1), backgroundColor: '#2ecc71', width: 200, …} length :  5
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

With recursive functions, you need to make sure that they terminate. For example, in your `findItem()`, you keep searching even when you found the node.

Have a look at the updated version, which resolves once a value is found:

```
function findItem(item) {

  function search(children) {
    for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      const child = children[i];
      if (child.Name === item) {
        return child; // <-------- we got it, terminate
      }
      if (child.children.length !== 0) {
        const inChild = search(child.children);
        if (inChild) return inChild // <-------- we got it further down, return that result
      }
    }
    return null // <------ nothing, keep going with outer function
  }

  return search(elements);
}
```

Your `findAndRemove()` has the same problem.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It did not work